# Conditionally Wrap React Parent from Grandchild

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an app like this:

```
<App>
  <Child_A>
    <Child_A_A />
  </Child_A>
</App>
```

At the level of Child_A_A I would like to affect the entire Dom, by being able to wrap App like this:

```
<ViewPortSettings>

  <App>
    <Child_A>
      <Child_A_A />
    </Child_A>
  </App>

</ViewPortSettings>
```

So basically I want some sort of variable or hook to affect whether the entire App is wrapped or not:

```
// Child_A_A.js
global.useViewport(true)
```

What are my options?

Comment: Why not just to pass function down to grandchild and toggle state in parent so the children are rendered inside ViewPortSettings or not?

Comment: I tried a solution with useContext from the child and it seems to work well. Only issue is I have to reset it on every router.navigation event or the Wrapper will stay in place because the Context variable remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create two versions you can make them into separate components then just make it conditionally:

```
{condition && <ViewPortSettings>
  <App>
    <Child_A>
      <Child_A_A />
    </Child_A>
  </App>
</ViewPortSettings>}
```

```
{!condition && <App>
  <Child_A>
    <Child_A_A />
  </Child_A>
</App>}
```

Comment: And what that condition will be? OP wants to set from Child_A_A

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your case, you must be using `useReducer` in case you want it to be resolved with react's core. I don't think `context` or any other way is suitable for this.

In your `Child_A_A` component, dispatch the action:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
// dispatch somewhere in your component
dispatch({type: 'wrap'})
```

In your main component, check the dispatched action:

```
const initialState = {show: false};

// Reducer    
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'wrap':
      return {show: true};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

// your main component:
function Main() {
  const [state] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    {state.show && <ViewPortSettings>}
      <App>
        <Child_A>
          <Child_A_A />
        </Child_A>
       </App>
    {state.show && </ViewPortSettings>}
  )
}
```

Comment: Your answer is harmful, it breaks few crucial React principles. It will not even render properly, app will surely crash. By the way - why do you assume that @dani uses redux and react hooks? -1

Comment: I'm not sure why is this so? And I'm not using redux anyway.

Comment: You should test your answer before posting it publicly at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Provide me a working example at codesandbox or somewhere and I will remove my downvote

Comment: I don't have that much time. Goodbye.

Comment: You didnt have time to test your answer neither.

Comment: `{state.show && <ViewPortSettings>}` will crash app immediately

Comment: I already have implemented in my real project. Anyways, bye. Need to sleep.